Conda channel remove fails
Installing a new venv in conda is taking more than 24 hours. I had conda-forge in the channels, and wanted to test whether the issue would be fixed by removal of conda forge.
After removal I'm left with only defaults as the channel, but conda install still looks in conda forge. Where does conda store the channels used for install?
conda config --show channels

Gives
channels:
  - defaults

conda config --get channels

Gives
--add channels 'defaults'   # lowest priority

But when I install a package:
conda install python=3.8

I get
Channels:
 - defaults
 - conda-forge
Platform: win-64
...

So I believe conda is still looking in conda-forge. I get the same behavior in the base environment and in the new environment. ~/.condarc only lists "defaults" as the channel.
Conda v 23.11.0, a related question
